# Remove / rebind SSL certificate from an Azure function using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to automate the process of obtaining an SSL certificate on my azure portal. For that I wrote an Azure function which downloads a new certificate and then uploads/binds it to my web app. The code looks like this:

```
        app.Update()
            .DefineSslBinding()
                .ForHostname("*.my.domain")
                .WithPfxCertificateToUpload(Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionDirectory, "cert.pfx"), "pwd")
                .WithSniBasedSsl()
                .Attach()
            .Apply();
```

which is supposed to upload a new certificate and create a new binding. It works as expected on a web app without existing certificates/bindings but if I run the function again I have some problems:

1. The new certificate doesn't appear in the azure portal
2. The binding remains the same
3. If I manually remove the binding and run my code again it'll create the same binding with the very first certificate I had, i.e. becomes the same again
4. Funny thing: I don't receive any failure

After some researching I figured out that if I list my certificates in the azure cli with `az webapp config ssl list` the list on the portal is updated, i.e. all the certificates were there. But that doesn't help much.

My general question would be: is there any other way of rebinding a certificate?

Or, as an obvious workaround would be to remove an existing binding and the certificate beforeahead: how can I do the SSL certificate removal in an azure function using the .NET SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the way. One should do this in 2 steps: first, upload a certificate with

```
        var certificate = await azure.AppServices.AppServiceCertificates
                .Define($"some-name")
                .WithRegion(app.Region)
                .WithExistingResourceGroup(app.ResourceGroupName)
                .WithPfxByteArray(pfxBytes)
                .WithPfxPassword("test")
                .CreateAsync();
```

and then using `WithExistingCertificate`:

```
        await app.Update()
            .DefineSslBinding()
                .ForHostname("*.my.domain")
                .WithExistingCertificate(certificate.Thumbprint)
                .WithSniBasedSsl()
                .Attach()
            .ApplyAsync();
```

There is a pending pull request in order to do that in a single call https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/pull/208

**UPD:**
The PR was merged so instead of 2 calls you can simply use a single one:

```
var certBytes = certificateService.RetreiveCertificate();
webapp
    .Update()
    .DefineSslBinding()
    .ForHostname("my.hostname")
    .WithPfxByteArrayToUpload(certBytes, "password")
    .WithSniBasedSsl()
    .Attach()
    .Apply();
```